# Data selected from three tables repeats itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created three tables (cars,colors and brand) with mysql. I want to select data from the three tables but the data are being repeated.

Note: Please the car_ID in the colors and brands table references the car_ID column from cars table.

```
cars table
car_ID | type
 1     | 300
 2     | 200

colors table
id | color | car_ID
 1 |  red  |  1
 2 |  blue |  1
 3 |  black|  2
 4 |  green|  2

brands
id | brand | car_ID
 1 |  BMW  |  1
 2 |  cst  |  1
 3 |  ash  |  2
 4 |  golf |  2

SELECT 
    a.car_ID
    b.color
    c.brand
FROM
    cars a
          INNER JOIN
                  colors b
              ON
                  a.car_ID=b.id
          INNER JOIN
                    brands c
              ON
                   a.car_ID=c.id
WHERE
      a.Car_ID=1;
```

This repeats the needed data, this is what i receive

```
Car_ID | colors | brands
1      | red    | BMW
1      | blue   | cst
1      | red    | BMW
1      | blue   | cst
```

However, the data below is what i desire to receive

```
id | colors | brands
1  | red    | BMW
1  | blue   | cst
```

**UPDATE**
Sorry guys, I have updated my tables data and hope this time around it make sense.
Please what am I doing wrong in my query above. Thanks for helping.

Comment: The structure and data of these tables make no sense. Why use an ID column if every row has the same ID number? Also, it make no sense to do a join on the basis that a car's ID number matches a color's ID number or a brand's ID number.

Comment: Why is the join from cars to brands an outer join instead of an inner join?

Comment: @EdCottrell the id column in colors and brands references the id column in cars.

Comment: You should probably clarify that in your question. There are still problems with your underlying logic, though. A car can't belong to two brands, for example. There is no reason why *any* query would return only `red` with `BMW`, and not `blue`, or why `blue` would match with only `cst` and not `BMW`.

Comment: @DanBracuk for the purpose of sampling i have changed it to inner join

Comment: You're relying on the order of the rows... this is absolutely not how Relational databases work.  For this example I'd actually think you'd want one table with four columns -- an Id, Car, Color, and Brand column.  The tables you have would make ok reference tables -- which you could use to enforce that the primary table only has valid values, but to get the results you want you need something that tells the data how to combine... row order is not sufficient, most databases will mix up row ordering at some point due to how the data is stored.

Comment: The query itself is fine.  The data or structure is flawed.  The structures listed do not show how a brand relates to a car, or how a color relates to a car.  since there is no UNIQUE relationship, the system is returning what you asked for in the query.  The data, or structure is flawed which is why you're not getting what you want.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you meant to have id=2 next to "blue" and "cst" in their respective tables, that would work, but it's still a non-standard way of doing things.

Comment: Hi guys, i have update my query and tables data, i hope it now make sense.Thanks

Comment: perhaps you have duplicate ids in the car table?

Answer (score 1):

(I typed this out.. then realised that I have no clue what you want to do... But I'll leave this out anyway)

Your tables aren't very well defined... here is my proposed table structure:

cars table

```
id | type_id | colour_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 2       | 4
```

Car type id

```
id | brand_id | name
1  | 1        | 300
2  | 1        | 200
```

Colours table

```
id | name
1  | Red
2  | Blue
3  | Black
4  | Green
```

Brands table:

```
id | name
1  | BMW
2  | cst
3  | ash
4  | golf
```

Query...

```
SELECT c.id as car_id, t.name as `type`, b.name as `brand`, co.name as `colour`
FROM cars c
    INNER JOIN types t ON t.id = cars.type_id
    INNER JOIN brands b ON b.id = t.brand_id
    INNER JOIN colours co ON co.id = c.colour_id
```

It should return something like below

```
car_id | type | brand | colour
1      | 300  | BMW   | Red
2      | 300  | BMW   | Green
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess from your question how everything works, but it seems like you might want ...

```
SELECT a.car_ID
       b.color
       c.brand
  FROM cars a
 INNER JOIN colors b ON a.car_ID=b.car_ID  /* changed ON criterion */
 INNER JOIN brands c ON a.car_ID=c.car_ID
 WHERE a.Car_ID=1
```

I'm guessing that you use `car_ID` throughout to relate the tables to each other.

Comment: I think this question is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/24437766/2349634