# Data from three tables duplicates when a JOIN statement is used

Tags: php, mysql, sql

when I retrieve data from my tables using JOIN, the rows duplicates. The tables are three in number.

```
Students
--------
StuID |    Name     |
1     | Appiah John | 
2     | Minister A  |

Levels
------
| LevelID | Level | Year  | StuID |
|  08     |  100  | 2010  |  2    |
|  83     |  200  | 2011  |  1    |
|  45     |  200  | 2011  |  2    |


Ranks
-----
| RankID | Rank | StuID |
|   101  | 1st  |  1    |
|   404  | 4th  |  2    |
```

This is my query statement to select some data from the three tables

```
SELECT 
    m.StuID,
    n.Level,
    n.Year,
    o.Rank
FROM
    Students m 
          INNER JOIN
                  Levels n
              ON
                  m.StuID=n.StuID
          INNER JOIN
                    Ranks o
              ON
                   m.StuID=o.StuID
WHERE
      m.StuID=2;
```

**OUTPUT**

The query above produces a duplicate answer

```
| StuID | Level | Year  |Rank  |
|  2    |  100  | 2010  | 4th  |
|  2    |  200  | 2011  | null |  
|  2    |  100  | 2010  | 4th  |
|  2    |  200  | 2011  | null |
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

I therefore wish that the output would be like below

```
| StuID | Level | Year  |Rank  |
|  2    |  100  | 2010  | 4th  |
|  2    |  200  | 2011  | null |
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Where am I going wrong?
2. Is join the best way to select data from three tables like this?
3. How can I make a query to get the desired output?

Comment: You should use "group by m.StuID"

Comment: Do a left join instead of inner.

Comment: @mkross1983 how would a left join help?

Comment: @tungbk29, it only produces a row instead of the two rows

Comment: I've got a question. How do you know rank 4th corresponds to the year 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not I think the comma between `Students m` and `INNER JOIN` is doing it. You're selecting from two separate tuples now, joined on any clause rather than joining the first table to the second to the third.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a left join instead of an inner join:

```
SELECT    m.StuID,
          n.Level,
          n.Year,
          o.Rank
FROM      Students m
LEFT JOIN Levels n ON (m.StuID = n.StuID)
LEFT JOIN Ranks o ON (m.StuID = o.StuID)
WHERE     m.StuID = 2
```

Comment: Please, your query gives me the same output (duplication)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `select distinct m.StuID`?

You can try something like this

```
SELECT distinct m.StuID, n.Level, n.Year, o.Rank 
    FROM Students m INNER JOIN Levels n ON m.StuID=n.StuID 
    INNER JOIN Ranks o 
    ON m.StuID=o.StuID WHERE m.StuID=2;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: you can try something like this SELECT distinct
    m.StuID,
    n.Level,
    n.Year,
    o.Rank
FROM
    Students m 
          INNER JOIN
                  Levels n
              ON
                  m.StuID=n.StuID
          INNER JOIN
                    Ranks o
              ON
                   m.StuID=o.StuID
WHERE
      m.StuID=2;

Comment: @user3600372 Edit your answer to include that information. Preferably use `code formatting` for it, as well.

Comment: The problem still persist, even though i have used the distinct

Comment: you can try using group by

Comment: @user3600372, using group by would fetch only a row instead of the two rows